# What's the best UI to use when asking a user for a negative selection (i.e. avoid X)?

Tags: multi-selection

Assume you're a dietitian asking what foods someone avoids (dietary restrictions), what's the best UI to use?

Some examples I've toyed with:

[image: Checkbox Selection]

Source code at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpKKNd

Is there a better way to display this UI or maybe ask it differently so there's no confusion as to what the user is selecting? Is there a technical term for this type of selection?

Comment: "Unselect" => "you want".  That is a very confusing contradiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overthinking this and causing some kind of weird double negative. You're asking for active user input - in order to *de*select - what the user *doesn't* want. That is a very confusing anti-pattern.

Just have the user actively select what they want to avoid from a plain list (no pre-checked boxes).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2DbMl.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Another solution might be to have dropdown menus which make it more explicit what is being selected:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZoJyF.png)</sup>

Comment: Any concern that this form makes it appear as though you want what you selected given the check mark next to each item?

Comment: @Omar I don't think so. It's a fairly common pattern to have users select something they want to avoid or remove. In the context of a dietary plan I think it would be pretty clear what selection is being made. I added another possible solution with dropdown menus which makes it more explicit.

Comment: It's also worth noting that on all medical forms, you specify allergies by the checking ones that you *have*, not the ones that you don't have.  Checking allergens that you want to avoid would be consistent with that.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid double negatives, use selection on what you want to avoid, BUT you could give a better reinforcement of the **avoidance** concept using striketrough text.

Something like that:

#### Select the allergenes you want to avoid:

[image: +] <strike>Nuts</strike>

[image: -] Dairy

Comment: Using a cross instead of a tick can also help indicating negativity.